# context as a parameter takes this in android and allow us to implement method of interface. Why so?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

**My Main Activity Class**
This is implemented to learn recycler view and to handle clicks. The below code works fine but while implementing listener I got confused. All the doubts are listed below. Do help.

```
package com.suasnom.pizzarecyclerview

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), isClickedInterface {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //implementing recycler view
         recycler_view.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val data = fetchData()
        val adapter = CustomAdapter(data, this)
        recycler_view.adapter = adapter

    }

    fun fetchData(): ArrayList<String> {
        val list_Strings = ArrayList<String>()
        var str = ""
        for(i in 1..100){
            str = "${i} line"
            list_Strings.add(str)
        }
        return list_Strings
    }

    override fun onItemClicked(item: String) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "$item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

In this statement I passed

```
val adapter = CustomAdapter(data, this)
```

and it allows me to override the below method:

```
override fun onItemClicked(item: String) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "$item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

The below code is for recycler view adapter where I write that interface:

```
package com.suasnom.pizzarecyclerview

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import android.view.View
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView


class CustomAdapter(val list_strings: ArrayList<String>, private val listner: isClickedInterface): RecyclerView.Adapter<PizzaViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PizzaViewHolder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false)
        val pizzaObject = PizzaViewHolder(view)
        view.setOnClickListener {
        listner.onItemClicked(list_strings[pizzaObject.adapterPosition])
         }
        return pizzaObject
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PizzaViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val data_incoming = list_strings[position]
        holder.text_message.text = data_incoming
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return list_strings.size
    }

}

class PizzaViewHolder(private val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    val text_message = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textrow)
}

interface isClickedInterface{
    fun onItemClicked(item: String){}
}
```

Any idea how this is working. Please Help ...

Answer (score 0):

inside `CustomAdapter` on the bottom you have declared `isClickedInterface` (it might be declared anywhere else or as separated file). it is implemented by your `MainActivity` (after `:`), so you have to set this interface methods inside implementing class - so in `Activity` appears `onItemClicked(item: String)` method

now your `CustomAdapter` have constructor param to pass this interface (second one). for initiating new instance of adapter you have pass implemented interface, in here you may pass whole `Activity` as it implements desired interface (`val adapter = CustomAdapter(data, this)` - `this` points on `Activity`, which is also an `isClickedInterface` interface instance)

now inside `onCreateViewHolder` you are setting `setOnClickListener` and inside of it you are calling method from passed interface in constructor